# 2D Jumping error

Tags: c++, collision-detection, box2d

Basically, here is my code:

```
bool Player::onCollision(BaseOBJ* obj)
{
    if(obj->name == "phys_static")
    {
        jumping = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

void Player::jump()
{
    if(jumping == true)
    {
        ApplyForce(Vec2(0.f, -13000.f), Vec2(0.f, 0.f));
        jumping = false;
    }
}

onCollision is called first, when there is a collision. It is not called if there has not been any new collisions (ex. only jumps would register, not moving from side to side)

It normally works fine, however if I hold the jump key all the way through the jump (from when it is launched to when it touches the ground) I cannot jump again. Any solutions?

Comment: Player::onCollision always return true, is that right?

Comment: the code that handles the keyboard events could maybe be more interesting.Otherwise I would maybe put some debug output in jump to see if the function is called and what value the jumping flag has.

Comment: This code raises more questions than it answers. What is the normal course of events? Is 'jumping` true or false before you press the jump key? Does pressing the jump key call `jump()`? Is `onCollision` called at the beginning of a jump, or the end, or both?...

Answer (score 0):

An often overlooked issue with holding down a key is that your operating system will convert this into fast, repeated presses.

Example:
In your text editor, hold the A key. One 'a' will appear, and then, after a slight delay:
aaaaaaaaaaaaa (Many repeated 'A' key presses are sent to the active application.)

Is your jump function being called repeatedly and somehow messing up how you intended your jump checking to work?

If not, please answer some of the questions that earlier commenters have presented.

P.S. Suggestion on the side: it appears to me that 'jumping' should be named 'canJump' or 'allowJumping'. This avoids a lot of confusion. Right now it sounds like it indicates whether you *are* jumping, whereas you actually use it to indicate whether you *can* jump.